# C# parsing a Vector2 from string

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I am trying to load a Vector2 into my game by reading it from a text file as a string and then parsing it. But when I try to load this info, I get this exception:

Format exception was unhandled.
Input string was not in a correct format.

Text file:

{X:512 Y:384}

Code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@fileName + ".txt");

string pos = objReader.ReadLine();

float aXPosition = float.Parse(pos.Substring(pos.IndexOf("X:"), pos.IndexOf(" Y")));
float aYPosition = float.Parse(pos.Substring(pos.IndexOf("Y:"), pos.IndexOf("}")));
```

So what I'm trying to do is reading the X and Y position from the text file. I found this technique here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/xnagamestudioexpress/thread/fd94cfec-f1f4-4cab-aa1d-8c72b524875b

Looks pretty simple, but for some reason it's not working for me.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are misusing `pos.Substring` method. Check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because `IndexOf` gives you index of ***X*** in ***X:*** you've specified in parameter. Try something like this:

```
System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@fileName + ".txt");

string pos = objReader.ReadLine();

int startInd = pos.IndexOf("X:") + 2;
float aXPosition = float.Parse(pos.Substring(startInd, pos.IndexOf(" Y") - startInd));
startInd = pos.IndexOf("Y:") + 2;
float aYPosition = float.Parse(pos.Substring(startInd, pos.IndexOf("}") - startInd));
```

**Update**

I've tested the code and there was also an issue with count parameter of `Substring` method. It should indicate length of the substring and **not** the end index in the original string. I updated the code, so it should work correctly now.

Comment: It still doesn't work unfortunately. Same exception, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Check the updated version of my code. I've used the file with same text and it worked correctly parsing both numbers.

Comment: Could anyone tell me why -1 voted? This solution works correctly and it the quickest way to fix the code in the question.

Comment: I'm happy to help you. I would be grateful if you marked my answer as solution and upvoted it then :).

Comment: I marked it as the solution, but unfortunately I can't upvote it yet since I have no reputation. I will upvote it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just use `XmlSerializer` instead, it will be a lot less work.

For example:

```
class MySaveGame
{
    public Vector2 Point1 { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Point2 { get; set; }
}
```

To Save:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySaveGame));
using (var stream = File.Create(@"C:\yourpath.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, new MySaveGame { Point1 = new Vector2(3, 3) });
}
```

To Read:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\yourpath.xml"))
{
    var mySave = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as MySaveGame;
}
```

That was off the top of my head, double check my code

Comment: I don't really feel like rewriting my code so I can use xml. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, it's only 6 lines.

Comment: I have also written code that saves data into a text file, so I would have to adjust my entire save function as well. And I have more variables than just the position. But it works now so all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Format exception was unhandled. Input string was not in a correct format.

You are getting this exception because you are trying to parse a string which is not a string representation of a float.

The String.Substring MSND documentation says:

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and has a specified length.

The second parameter is the length of the string you want to extract not the index where to stop the extraction and that explains your issues.

In fact:

Given this string `{X:512 Y:384}`, `pos.IndexOf("X:")` = 1, `pos.IndexOf(" Y")`= 6

=> `pos.Substring(pos.IndexOf("X:"), pos.IndexOf(" Y"))`

=> `pos.Substring(1 , 6)`

=> `X:512` and this is not a float!

Back to the **solution** to your problem:

1. Clean the string from all non numeric characters (leave the blank space in between)
2. The resulting string should now only contain the values you want and a space in between
3. Split your string. You now have an array with 2 strings containing the values your want, just parse them.

Here is a sample code for doing this:

```
                                               //"{X:512 Y:384}"
String cleanString = pos.Replace("{X:", "");   //"512 Y:384}"
cleanString = cleanString .Replace("Y:", "");  //"512 384}"
cleanString = cleanString .Replace("}", "");   //"512 384"
String[] xyVals = cleanString.Split(' ');      //"512" and "384"
float aXPosition = float.Parse(xyVals[0]);
float aYPosition = float.Parse(xyVals[1]);
```

Comment: Lucas' reply solved my problem already, but thanks for the answer.